# Unity isometric collision detection - sticking to walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm trying to get a decent collision system for my Unity game.

I use OnTriggerEnter and 'Exit to set and unset a 'collided' flag.

I remember the last position of my character before each move.

I then make a move and use the OnTriggerEnter flag to reset the character back to the last position it was at before moving if there was a collision.

The problem is I'm getting stuck to walls quite often and the above method seems overly complex and I'm wondering if I'm missing a more straightforward approach.

Does the above seem like a reasonable strategy for collision detection in an isometric game?

Thanks

s

Answer (score 0):

sure, thats what we did back in the day before unity came in to play,
personally i always used a future ghost, a invisible player that took the step and then told the player if it was okay or not. i didnt like to throw the player around to much.
and you always have to check that the player will not enter the red zone.

Lets say that we jumped inside a red zone and figured out that this is not the place i am suppose to be, so we take a step back, but a step back does not mean we went out of the red zone, we just approced the border a bit.

by using a ghost we ensure that the player never enters the red zone. but a ghost would send back a message to the player saying "no no" to this way.

an example would be we take 1 step inside the red zone, our velocity will bring us 1.1 inside the red zone before the logic to step 1 back kicks in, which means that we will be 0.1 inside the red zone, but our script didnt pick that up because it didnt take the velocity drifting over time in to account.
This was in my experience the most difficult and fun part, going from a cubic move to a more action pack time sensitive one, where you have to take velocity in to consideration, thats why they call it physics engines and not bounding box checking engines. haha.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the ghost player is something I'll definatelt try. You mentioned that that was what you did before Unity, what do you use in Unity to do this?